# How do I launch My browser with My set up extensions by puppeter?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I have some specific extension set up in my Chromium browser. I need to run and control it by `puppeteer` with that extension. But I'm not able to do so: browser starting up without any installed extensions.
Here is my `launch` block:

```js
puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser',
  userDataDir: '/home/<my_regular_username>/.config/chromium/Default',
  headless: false,
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions","--enable-automation"],
  args: [
    '--incognito',
    '--window-size=1400,800'
  ],
})
```

Those `executablePath` and `executablePath` values I've copied from `chrome://version` page.
WAIDW???

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path to each extension. If you want to load multiple extensions, you can do something like this:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
        '--load-extension=path/to/unpacked/extension1,path/to/unpacked/extension2',
    ],
});
```

Comment: thank you @erik will it pick up the settings for that extension? it requires API KEY

Comment: @Stamper I'm not sure, if you also load the user data directory it should

Comment: could you please provide me correct command or parameter name?

Comment: @Stamper You specified it yourself in the original question, userDataDir

Comment: `userDataDir` doesn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: thanks @erik for help! I've found the solution. `userDataDir` parameter value should be without `Default` at the end of the path. and one more item in the `args` array is required: `--profile-directory=Default`